# How to set a schema for my csv data automatically?

Tags: apache-spark

I use the following code to set a schema to my csv data in JAVA:

```
StructType schema =  createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                createStructField("col1", IntegerType, true),
                createStructField("col2", IntegerType, true)));

Dataset<Row> dF = spark.read().format("csv").schema(schema).load("filepath/file.csv");
```

But how do i set the schema if it is specified in the first line of the `file.csv` file (comma as a seperator of column names) (`col1, col2,...`) and without using a prior `StructType` definition of a schema

Answer (score 1):

you can't,

because Spark can't infer Data type from csv file, he can only infer column name if you specifie `header=true` (DataType will be String)

Comment: `header=true` where ? could you be more specific ?